# Tilt-shift image effect with CIFilter

Tags: swift, imageview, cifilter

I have a circle imageview. I set its image and gave Tonal effect as with below which works.

```
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectTonal")!
    filter.setDefaults()
    ...

    filter.setValue(startImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    let filteredImageData = filter.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
    let filteredImage = ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageData, fromRect: filteredImageData.extent)
```

I want to give another effect, like tilt shift on Instagram,  to make the photo brighter/blurred on the edges of my imageview. This way, the color difference between circular imageview and background will be eliminated/less.

Is there any way to make it happen?

Comment: Apple has an example for this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_filer_recipes/ci_filter_recipes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH4-SW17

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved my issue with the following code.

Thanks @Eric D, your link showed me the road.

```
 func vignetteEffect(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {

    let originalImage = image
    let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
        let startImage = CIImage(image: originalImage)


        // Vignette Effect
        let vignetteFilter = CIFilter(name:"CIVignette")!
        vignetteFilter.setDefaults()


        let radius = 8

        vignetteFilter.setValue(startImage, forKey:kCIInputImageKey)
        vignetteFilter.setValue(-5, forKey:"inputIntensity")
        vignetteFilter.setValue(radius, forKey:"inputRadius")

        let filteredImageData = vignetteFilter.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
        let filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageData, fromRect: filteredImageData.extent)

        return UIImage(CGImage: filteredImageRef)

    }
```